# Showing "Your application may not have access to email addresses" when try to get email address of twitter user using Fabric Twitter SDK

Tags: ios, email, twitter

I'd like to request the user's Twitter mail. On https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/request-email

Code is:

```
if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {
    TWTRShareEmailViewController* shareEmailViewController =
    [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc]
     initWithCompletion:^(NSString* email, NSError* error) {
         if (error)
         {
            NSLog(@"Error  %@",error.localizedDescription);

         }else
         {
             NSLog(@"Email %@",email);
         }

     }];
    [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: All you've done here is copy and past the sample code from Twitter's documentation.  Is your application whitelisted, because the page you linked to says that your application has to be whiteleisted to get this information.  What have you tried?  What results are you getting?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get the email from twitter ?

Comment: No , i didn't get any email from twitter !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this link https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform to submit a request for your app to be granted for user's email address. Choose any one of the the options and fill all the information.

Here is the example after you get permission:
check on this URL : https://apps.twitter.com/app/APP_ID/permissions

[image]

Comment: i already tried "I have a technical question about the Twitter API" but i won't get any response.

Comment: your pending case will be shown on Dashboard of ur Fabric account on the web.